# How to create backorder programatically magento 2?

Tags: magento2, orders, programmatically

I am using the following code to add products to `Quote` object which throws an error if the product is `out of stock`.

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
$product->setTaxClassId($this->getTaxClassId())
        ->setPrice($price)
        ->setSpecialPrice($price)
        ->setTierPrice([])
        ->setBasePrice($baseprice)
        ->setOriginalCustomPrice($price)
        ->setRowTotal($rowTotal)
        ->setBaseRowTotal($rowTotal);
/** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
$quote->addProduct($product, (int)$qty);
```

How do I override the product qty check and create a `backorder` for each case ?

Comment: First, You do not need any customization for this required.if just need to enable back order setting at product inventory section. Open a product at admin, From Inventory section ,make `backorder` field value  to `Allow Qty Below 0 and Notify Customer` .

Comment: @AmitBera I am well aware of the settings available in `configuration`, but I need to override it irrespective of `Allow Qty Below 0 and Notify Customer` .

Comment: why you donot want use this setting?

Comment: It will enable the backorder for the complete Website, but I need it only while creating order `programmatically`.

Comment: You can enable also for specific product wise from the product level. Open a product  at admin and  `Open a product at admin, From Inventory section , make backorder field value to Allow Qty Below 0 and Notify Customer`

Comment: Not helpful, anyways thanks

Comment: Have u check this feature at default magento?

Comment: Yes, but that enables for the whole website, I want `Only` for the programmatically created order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My other question solved the problem. [What does “setIsSuperMode” do on Quote Object in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/281183/59216)

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
$product->setTaxClassId($this->getTaxClassId())
        ->setPrice($price)
        ->setSpecialPrice($price)
        ->setTierPrice([])
        ->setBasePrice($baseprice)
        ->setOriginalCustomPrice($price)
        ->setRowTotal($rowTotal)
        ->setBaseRowTotal($rowTotal);

/** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
$quote->setIsSuperMode(true);
$quote->addProduct($product, (int)$qty);
```

> Essentially it is a flag on the quote that this quote has been created by an admin.
>   The effect of this is in the locations you stated that an admin can, for example, create an order for an item that normally would be out of stock or is not visible in the catalog.

Comment: I am aware of `not visible in the catalog` but not aware of the stock check. Good answer.

Comment: Hello @Milind i have try same solution for my order that created programmatically , but not working from my side , can you please suggest

Answer (score 0):

you can get the product stock and put the condition on that, here is a code for getting product stock.

```
<?php
namespace vendor\module\Block;
class ProductStock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_stockItemRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository $stockItemRepository,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_stockItemRepository = $stockItemRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getStockItem($productId)
    {
        return $this->_stockItemRepository->get($productId);
    }
}
?>

<?php
    $id = 123;
    $_productStock = $block->getStockItem($id);
    //print_r($_productStock->getData()); 
    echo $_productStock->getQty(); echo '<br />';
    echo $_productStock->getMinQty(); echo '<br />';
    echo $_productStock->getMinSaleQty(); echo '<br />';
    echo $_productStock->getMaxSaleQty(); echo '<br />';
    echo $_productStock->getIsInStock(); echo '<br />';
?>
```

Comment: Yes, I already know that, But I have a different question here.
How do I create a `Backorder` If the product is out of stock, and programmatically?

Comment: then you have to make product manage stock to "No" or programmatically add the quantity and make a product in stock