# What does "setIsSuperMode" do on Quote Object in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, quote, programmatically

I am creating a `Quote` programmatically, I have found a field `IsSuperMode` on `Quote` object.

What effect does it have on the `Quote` ?

Class: `/Magento/Backend/Model/Session/Quote.php`

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/c20732c44c3373dec86e40e5885969a46a6524ef/app/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Session/Quote.php#L173
[image: /Magento/Backend/Model/Session/Quote.php]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Reference Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/29542/72911)

The quote is set into super mode in
`app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Session/Quote.php`:

```
$this->_quote->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

Essentially it is a flag on the quote that this quote has been created by an admin. The effect of this is in the locations you stated that an admin can for example create an order for an item that normally would be out of stock or is not visible in the catalog.

Comment: This answer was a copy of https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/29542

Comment: Oh yes i add reference link for this answer